# Locust - Split equal number if users across workers

Tags: performance-testing, locust

I am running locust in distributed mode with 3 workers with configuration file.

**Master conf:**

[image]

**Worker conf:**

[image]

My Use case is If I am running 15 users then I have run 5 users in each worker. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 1):

Set `users` to 15. Users are automatically distributed as evenly as possible across workers.

You could/should also set `expect-workers` to 3, to ensure the load doesnt start until all workers are connected.